# How to solve AppBarLayout with DrawerLayout Error

Tags: android, drawerlayout, android-appbarlayout

```
    <android.support.v4.widget.DrawerLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
        xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
        xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="match_parent"
        android:id="@+id/drawer_layout"
        android:fitsSystemWindows="true"
        tools:context="com.example.sujin.trinity.HomePageActivity">

        <android.support.design.widget.AppBarLayout
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:theme="@style/AppTheme.AppBarOverlay"

            android:background="#ffffff">

            <android.support.v7.widget.Toolbar
                android:id="@+id/toolbar"
                android:layout_width="match_parent"
                android:layout_height="?attr/actionBarSize"
                android:background="?attr/colorPrimary"
                app:popupTheme="@style/AppTheme.PopupOverlay" />

        </android.support.design.widget.AppBarLayout>

        <include layout="@layout/content_home_page" />
        <fragment
            android:id="@+id/fragment_navigation_drawer"
            android:layout_width="350dp"
            android:layout_height="match_parent"
            android:layout_gravity="start"
            app:layout="@layout/fragment_navigation_drawer"
            tools:layout="@layout/fragment_navigation_drawer"
            android:name="com.example.sujin.trinity.NavigationDrawerFragment"
            />
            </android.support.v4.widget.DrawerLayout>
```

Here is the `content` layout file:

```
        <?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
        <RelativeLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
        xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
        xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="match_parent"
        android:paddingBottom="@dimen/activity_vertical_margin"
        android:paddingLeft="@dimen/activity_horizontal_margin"
        android:paddingRight="@dimen/activity_horizontal_margin"
        android:paddingTop="@dimen/activity_vertical_margin"
        app:layout_behavior="@string/appbar_scrolling_view_behavior"
        tools:context="com.example.sujin.trinity.HomePageActivity"
        tools:showIn="@layout/activity_home_page">

        <CalendarView
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:id="@+id/calendarView"
            android:layout_alignParentTop="true"
            android:layout_centerHorizontal="true"
            android:layout_marginTop="182dp" />

        <TextView
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:textAppearance="?android:attr/textAppearanceLarge"
            android:text="Large Text"
            android:id="@+id/textView"
            android:layout_alignParentTop="true"
            android:layout_centerHorizontal="true"
            android:layout_marginTop="84dp"
            android:textColor="#000000" />
    </RelativeLayout>
```

[image: When <code>android:background="#ffffff"</code> is used, following output is observed but the other elements like TextView are not visible.]

[[image: When <code>android:background</code> is not used, following output is observed but the other elements like TextView are not visible.]

When `android:background="#ffffff"` is used, first output is observed but the  other elements like TextView are not visible.

When `android:background="#ffffff"` is not used, second output is observed but the  other elements like TextView are not visible. 
How do I solve this error?

Comment: What TextView are you trying to show? Please include your content layout.

Comment: The `AppBarLayout` needs to be inside the main content `ViewGroup`. Right now, it's acting as the main content itself. Put the `AppBarLayout` and the `<include>`d layout inside another `ViewGroup`; e.g., a `LinearLayout` or a `RelativeLayout`.

Comment: @cricket_007 I have added the content layout

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/a/36250434/5901637

Answer (score 0):

why use fragment for fragment_navigation_drawer????
use from standard code of android studio, like below:

```
<android.support.v4.widget.DrawerLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
    xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
    android:id="@+id/drawer_layout"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    android:fitsSystemWindows="true"
    tools:openDrawer="start">

    <include
        layout="@layout/app_bar_main"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="match_parent" />

    <android.support.design.widget.NavigationView
        android:id="@+id/nav_view"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="match_parent"
        android:layout_gravity="start"
        android:fitsSystemWindows="true"
        app:headerLayout="@layout/nav_header_main"
        app:menu="@menu/activity_main_drawer" />
</android.support.v4.widget.DrawerLayout>
```

and make another xml for your toolbar and content like below:

```
<android.support.design.widget.CoordinatorLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
    xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    android:fitsSystemWindows="true"
    tools:context=".MainActivity">

    <android.support.design.widget.AppBarLayout
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:theme="@style/AppTheme.AppBarOverlay">

        <android.support.v7.widget.Toolbar
            android:id="@+id/toolbar"
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="?attr/actionBarSize"
            android:background="?attr/colorPrimary"
            app:popupTheme="@style/AppTheme.PopupOverlay" />

    </android.support.design.widget.AppBarLayout>

    <include layout="@layout/content_home_page" />

</android.support.design.widget.CoordinatorLayout>
```

I hope it can help you.